# filter query using array in php

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a filter query using array value.It works. But if the array value is null, it does not work. If I create from start, it works even for null. I want to create it dynamically.

**Here is my code**

```
            $city_array=array('yangon','mandalay','myeik');
            $data_city=implode("','",$city_array);          

            $brand_array=array('huawei','samsung','sony');
            $data_brand=implode("','",$brand_array);

            $camera_array=array('rear camera');
            $data_camera=implode("','",$camera_array);

            $operator_array=array('mpt');
            $data_operator=implode("','",$operator_array);

            $size_array=array('');
            $data_size=implode("','",$size_array);

            $ram_array=array('');
            $data_ram=implode("','",$ram_array);

            $memory_array=array('');
            $data_memory=implode("','",$memory_array);

            $feature_array=array('');
            $data_feature=implode("','",$feature_array);


            $query = mysql_query ("     
             select cp.product_id,
             temp_operator.nid, temp_operator.operator1, temp_operator.operator2, temp_operator.operator3, temp_operator.operator4,
             temp_camera.camera1,temp_camera.camera2,
             temp_feature.feature1,temp_feature.feature2,temp_feature.feature3,temp_feature.feature4,temp_feature.feature5, 
             n.title as model,
             f_manage.filename as image,
             fprice.commerce_price_amount AS price,
             ttdcondition.name as `condition`,
             ttd.name as manufacture,
             ttdcity.name as city,
             ttdsize.name as display_size,
             ttdram.name as ram,
             ttdmemory.name as memory


             FROM temp_table_1 as temp_operator
             INNER JOIN node as n     
             INNER JOIN field_data_field_product as fdfp
             INNER JOIN commerce_product as cp
             INNER JOIN temp_table_2 as temp_camera
             INNER JOIN temp_table_3 as temp_feature

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_field_product_image as f_product_image
             INNER JOIN
             file_managed as f_manage

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_commerce_price as fprice

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_field_ph_condition as fcondition
             INNER JOIN
             taxonomy_term_data as ttdcondition

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_field_brand as fbrand
             INNER JOIN
             taxonomy_term_data as ttd

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_field_city as fcity
             INNER JOIN
             taxonomy_term_data as ttdcity

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_field_ph_display_size as fsize
             INNER JOIN
             taxonomy_term_data as ttdsize

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_field_ram as fram
             INNER JOIN
             taxonomy_term_data as ttdram

             INNER JOIN
             field_data_field_ph_internal_memory as fmemory
             INNER JOIN
             taxonomy_term_data as ttdmemory

             ON temp_operator.nid = n.nid
             AND temp_camera.nid = n.nid
             AND temp_feature.nid = n.nid
             AND fdfp.entity_id=n.nid
             AND fdfp.field_product_product_id =cp.product_id
             AND f_product_image.entity_id = cp.product_id
             AND f_product_image.field_product_image_fid = f_manage.fid
             AND fprice.entity_id=cp.product_id

             AND fcondition.field_ph_condition_tid=ttdcondition.tid
             AND n.nid=fcondition.entity_id

             AND  fbrand.field_brand_tid=ttd.tid
             AND fbrand.entity_id=n.nid

             AND fcity.field_city_tid=ttdcity.tid
             AND n.nid=fcity.entity_id

             AND ttdsize.tid=fsize.field_ph_display_size_tid
             AND n.nid=fsize.entity_id

             AND ttdram.tid=fram.field_ram_tid
             AND n.nid=fram.entity_id

             AND ttdmemory.tid=fmemory.field_ph_internal_memory_tid
             AND n.nid=fmemory.entity_id

             where ttd.name in ('$data_brand')      
             and ttdcity.name in ('$data_city')
             and ttdcondition.name in ('$data_condition')
             and ttdmemory.name in ('$data_memory')
             and ttdram.name in ('$data_ram')
             and (temp_camera.camera1 in ('$data_camera') or temp_camera.camera2 in ('$data_camera'))
             and ttdsize.name in ('$data_size')
             and (temp_operator.operator1 in ('$data_operator') or temp_operator.operator2 in ('$data_operator')
                  or temp_operator.operator3 in ('$data_operator') or temp_operator.operator4 in ('$data_operator'))
             and (temp_feature.feature1 in ('$data_feature') or temp_feature.feature2 in ('$data_feature')
                  or temp_feature.feature3 in ('$data_feature') or temp_feature.feature4 in ('$data_feature')
                  or temp_feature.feature5 in ('$data_feature') )     
             ") or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $row_array[]=$row;
        }
?>
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by "works" and "does not work" here. It's also not obvious what might be null (`$city_array`, `$city_array[0]`, or some maybe just one value in `$city_array`). The main issue with this code is that if a value in one of the arrays contains a quote mark (') you will get a broken mysql query.